# xmlquery returns all values as one long line instead of separate entities

Tags: sql, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to query the telephone numbers from the following xml file

```
<xmlPhoneEntity>
    <TelephoneEntity>
        <number>123</number>
    </TelephoneEntity>
    <TelephoneEntity>
        <number>456</number>
    </TelephoneEntity>
    <TelephoneEntity>
        <number>789</number>
    </TelephoneEntity>
</xmlPhoneEntity>
```

This XML is located in my DB - the table looks like this

```
    id    customer_id     telephone  blabla
    1       111            xmlfile
    2       222            xmlfile
```

etc

My sql query looks like this -

```
select xmlserialize(xmlquery('/xmlPhoneEntity/TelephoneEntity/number/text()

  passing telephone"
```

the response: 123456789

I tried using /nodes() instead of /text() and the result is the same.
How do I separate the values ?

Comment: What DB? MySQL? MSSQL?

Comment: I am using db2. is there a difference?